# Locking a partition/drive

Tags: encryption, windows, disk-encryption, truecrypt

I am working in an environment where people share the same PC running Windows 7. I would like to put my private files in an encrypted partition so that I can lock it when I leave the PC, yet leave the system available for someone else do use (physical access) and unlock it when I return without rebooting the entire system.

We do not have a file server available.
Our version of Windows does not have BitLocker installed.

Is this possible using preferably a free software?

Comment: this is not the right site to ask for software recommendation. also, this seems to be a [dublicate of this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64209/a-folder-lock-encryption-program-that-can-do-this/64214#64214)

Comment: Is the someone else logging on with a different set of credentials? If so, then you might not need to encrypt, just set permissions to the files. (An administrator of the PC can still read them, hence you might still need to encrypt)

Comment: Yes, all users are administrators.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Truecrypt to achieve this: http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/

Though you may have read that it isn't supported any longer it is likely to still be suitable for your situation. Another option would be something like an IronKey encrypted USB stick or similar.

Yet another option would be to use an encrypted Zip file: http://www.7-zip.org/7z.html

With any of these options you need to be wary of temporary files and caches that may be created of files / fragments left in memory etc.

Comment: Thanks. Truecrypt does exactly what I need, however I am not sure if I can trust it. With a 7z archive you need to extract/update the archive all the time and remember to clear all temp directories. I am actually looking for something that allow you to work directly on the encrypted folder, like Truecrypt.